# How to filter DB results with permissions stored in another DB

Tags: mysql, microservices

i'm currently searching for a good approach to filter DB results based on permissions which are stored in another services DB.
Let me first show the current state:
There's one Document-Service with 2 tables (permission, document) in its MySQL DB. When documents for a user are requested, a paginated result should be returned. For brevity let's ignore the pagination for now.

```
Permission table:           Document table:
user_id| document_id        document_id| more columns
-------|------------        A
1      | A                  B
2      | A                  C
2      | B
2      | C
```

The following request "*GET /documents/{userId}*" will result in the following query against the DB:

```
SELECT d.* FROM document d JOIN permission p WHERE p.user_id = '{userId}' AND p.document_id = d.document_id;
```

That's the current implementation and now i am asked to move the permission table into its own service. I know, one would say that's not a good idea, but this question is just a broken down example and in the real scenario it's a more meaningful change than it looks like. So let's take it as a "must-do".

Now my problem: After i move the table into another DB, i cannot use it in the sql query of Document-Service anymore to filter results.

- I also cannot query everything and filter in code, because there will be too much data AND i must use pagination which is currently implemented by LIMIT/OFFSET in the query (ignored in this example for brevity).
- I am not allowed to access a DB from any other application except its service.

My question is: **Is there any best practise or suggested approach for this kind of situation?**

I already had 2 ideas which i would like to list here, even though i'm not really happy with either of them:

- Query all document_ids of a user from the new Permission-Service and change the SQL to "SELECT * FROM document WHERE document_id IN {doc_id_array_from_permission_service}". The array could get pretty big and the statement slow; not happy about that.
- Replicate the permission table into Document-Service DB on startup and keep the query as it is. But then i need to implement a logic/endpoint to update the table in the Document-Service whenever it changes in the Permission-Service otherwise it get's out of sync. This feels like i'm duplicating so much logic in both services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of this answer, I'm going to assume that it is logical for Permissions to exist completely independently of Documents.  That is to say - if the ONLY place a `Permission` is relevant is with respect to a `DocumentID`, it probably does not make sense to split them up.

That being the case, either of the two options you laid out could work okay; both have their caveats.

**Option 1: Request Documents with ID Array**

This could work, and in your simplified example you could handle pagination prior to making the request to the `Documents` service.  But, this requires a coordinating service (or an API gateway) that understands the logic of the intended actions here.  It's doable, but it's not terribly portable and might be tough to make performant.  It also leaves you the challenge of now maintaining a full, current list of `DocumentID`s in your Permissions service which feels upside-down.  Not to mention the fact that if you have Permissions related to other entities, those all have to get propagated as well.  Suddenly your Permissions service is dabbling in lots of areas not specifically related to permissions.

**Option 2: Eventual Consistency**

This is the approach I would take.  Are you using a Messaging Plane in your Microservices architecture?  If so, this is where it shines!  If not, you should [look into it](https://solace.com/blog/messaging-between-microservices/).

So, the way this would work is any time you make a change to Permissions, your Permissions Service generates a `permissionUpdatedForDocument` event containing the relevant new/changed Permissions info.  Your `Documents` service (and any other service that cares about permissions) subscribes to these events and stores its own local copy of relevant information.  This lets you keep your join, pagination, and well-bounded functionality within the `Documents` service.

There are still some challenges.  I'd try to keep your `Permissions` service away from holding a list of all the `DocumentID` values.  That may or may not be possible.  Are your permissions Role or Group-based?  Or, are they document-specific?  What Permissions does the `Documents` service understand?

If permissions are indeed tied explicitly to individual documents, and especially if there are different levels of permission (instead of just binary yes/no access), then you'll have to rethink the structure in your `Permissions` service a bit.  Something like this:

```
Permission table:
user_id| entity_type| entity_id | permission_type
-------|------------|-----------|----------------
1      | document   | A         | rwcd
2      | document   | A         | r
2      | document   | B         | rw
2      | document   | C         | rw
1      | other      | R         | rw
```

Then, you'll need to publish `serviceXPermissionUpdate` events from any Service that understands permissions for its entities whenever those permissions change.  Your `Permissions` service will subscribe to those and update its own data.  When it does, it will generate its own event and your `Documents` service will see confirmation that its change has been processed and accepted.

This sounds like a lot of complication, but it's easy to implement, performant, and does a nice job of keeping each service pretty well contained.  The Messaging plane is where they interact with each other, and only via well-defined contracts (message names, formats, etc.).

Good luck!

Comment: The permission is a n-m relationship (users-documents), i cannot use a role/group from e.g. the token. Also the permission must be respected in other services which store additional data belonging to the document. They also must only return them if the user has permission to the belonging documents. The reason why it should be moved into a central place. About the Message Plane, i am aware of that and we already use it for other cases. Actually that would be my approach, too, if i decide for option 2. I just wanted to get more opinions, as i felt like there is a better approach overall.

Comment: For completeness: i did not find any better solution than option 2, so i go with that. It's the most suitable way so far to let PermissionService be the owner of the permissions and all other services get a copy table which can be updated / purged, but it must never be modified other than through the event on a message Q from PermissionService. Thanks for your additional information to this option 2.